# Detect attribute(type) change of input element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, security, passwords

How to restrict to change input type password to text in Inspection in java Script or jquery. If someone tries to open the input type password element in the developer menu and tries to change the type from password to text, this makes the password appears in text box.

if we can detect any attribute change that may do the work, but I am not sure if that would work if we make changes from the developer menu.

Comment: Assuming by 'in inspection' you mean the DOM viewer in devtools, then you can't - you cannot stop the user changing anything and everything about the DOM on the client side. This is why it's vital you perform all security and business logic validation on the server side. Anything validated on the client side should be done purely as a convenience to the user and should not be relied on for data integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, In javascript we dont have any straight approach with which we can detect the type or attribute change in javascript. I had same kind of problem and then after some studies, I found that this could be done with Mutation observer.
In this code I have created an extension method for HTMLElement and all we have to do is get the reference of that HTMLElement and call this extension function and pass the callback, which we want to be run on attribute change.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.onAttributeChange = function (c) {
    let observer = new MutationObserver(c);
    observer.observe(this,{attributes:true});
};
var elem=document.getElementById("txtpassword");
elem.onAttributeChange(function(){
        alert("attribute changed");
});
```

```html
<html>
    <title> 
    </title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="txtpassword" >
        
    </body>
</html>
```